# How to get all registered service types in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I have an Autofac container and I would like to be able to retrieve all the registered service types (not the implementation types, but the types they are registered as).

How can I get this information from an `IComponentContext`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var services =
    context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.SelectMany(x => x.Services)
           .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
           .Select(x => x.ServiceType);
```

Comment: Had to change the Select to a Where in order to get back an IEnumerable of services. var services =
    context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.SelectMany(x => x.Services)
           .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
           .Where(x => x.ServiceType);

Comment: @NovaJoe: That's not possible: your code wouldn't compile, because `ServiceType` is not a `bool`. And it wouldn't make too much sense anyway...

Comment: Sorry, forgot a part of the statement: var services = container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.SelectMany(x => x.Services).OfType<IServiceWithType>().Where(x => x.ServiceType == serviceType); Note the equality check for a specific service Type. Also, I have container instead of context, which is an AutoFac IContainer.

Comment: It is dangerous if you are filtering from any childscope. Registrations are scoped with its lifetimescope. This filtering could be null if your requested type is locating on root scope.

Answer (score -2):

How i resolved it

```
    var alldb = (from r in MasterDataFactory.Container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
                let s = r.Services.Where(i => i is KeyedService).Select(i => i as KeyedService).FirstOrDefault()
                where s!=null && s.ServiceType==typeof(ISomeInterface)
                select s).ToList();
```